# Not able to install python library on windows 10 server

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, windows-server-2012, pst

I am already install Microsoft Visual C++ 2014 on my server.But not install full visual studio setup on server because space issue.
I am trying to install this library.

```
pip install libpff-python
```

I am using above library for outlook PST data extraction.Its working fine on my local machine.
But, I am getting error on server like in attachment .[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best way to install the python library on windows is to download the most stable tar.gz file from https://github.com/libyal/libpff/releases and then install it using pip.

For example, `pip install libpff-experimental-20180714.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

I have see there you trying to install the PST library which are in development and it's Microsoft library so to hard to run on python.
I thought you will need to install all the all package regarding to the C++.

```
      pip install libpff-python
```

Also, if possible you can refer the GitHub questions tree.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with python 3.7.4.

After installing python 3.7.3 instead, I was able to install the library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  visualcpp build tools from microsoft website. For example,
Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)